# Need some help debugging simple Rails undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We're using Rails4,  Ruby2.

Whenever I visit the signup on the app, it throws an error:

```
undefined method `plan_id=' for #<User:0x007f0721517f28>
```

Here is the full UsersController:

http://hastebin.com/titisaweva.rb

Here is the full User model:

http://hastebin.com/tuhokinabi.rb

Here is the Plan model:

```
class Plan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

The errors says that there's an issue of line 16 of the UsersController:

```
if !ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY'] || params[:coupon]
  @user.plan_id = Plan.find_by_stripe_id('free').id
end
```

I am somewhat new to rails and am having a hard time figuring out what might cause this issue.  If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's lines 15-17 of your `UsersController`:

```
 if !ENV['STRIPE_API_KEY'] || params[:coupon]
   @user.plan_id = Plan.find_by_stripe_id('free').id
 end
```

You are attempting to assign a value to the  `plan_id` attribute, but a field for that attribute does not exist within your `users` table. You need to add this field using a migration:

```
rails g migration add_plan_id_to_users plan_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Thanks alot, the field was actually in the local migration, but didn't make it to the remote version somehow.  I just overwrote the original one, and pushed it live and works.